# Minimise select to a singular one instead of multiple

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am currently encountering an issue with retrieving data from both tables in single query. The general idea is that I need to perform a search using keywords that should be in either name of the image, it's description or as a tag associated with it (or) as well as match a specific mood (and) (I know my code might be a bit spaghetti, bear with me, I'm very new to this). The relationship between tag table and the image table must be many to many (for now I chose fetch as lazy as it generates less queries than eager, I understand that there might be issues with that). Here are my entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="image")
@Builder
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    private byte[] content;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "mood")
    private Mood mood;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "image_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Tag() {}

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "image_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
    )
    private Set<Image> images = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And my specification:

```
@Repository
public interface SearchSpecification{

    static Specification<Image> searchWithKeywordAndMood(List<String> keywords, Mood mood) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<Image, Tag> tagJoin = root.join("tags");

            Predicate keywordPredicates = null;

            for (String keyword : keywords) {
                Predicate nameLike = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%");
                Predicate descriptionLike = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("description"), "%" + keyword + "%");
                Predicate tagLike = criteriaBuilder.like(tagJoin.get("name"), "%" + keyword + "%");

                Predicate keywordPredicate = criteriaBuilder.or(nameLike, descriptionLike, tagLike);
                keywordPredicates = (keywordPredicates == null) ? keywordPredicate : criteriaBuilder.or(keywordPredicates, keywordPredicate);
            }

            Predicate moodPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("mood"), mood);

            return criteriaBuilder.and(keywordPredicates, moodPredicate);
        };
    }

}
```

As well as search repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SearchRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Image, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Image> {

    Page<Image> findAll(Specification<Image> spec, Pageable pageable);

}
```

I need the results to be pageable. I read in similar posts that returning a set might minimize the amount of queries, but not really sure how to implement this, additionally most questions are related to many to one or one to many types. Results with my current set up with lazy is amount of images found + 1 extra select:
[Hibernate results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzxIP.png)